# Opencover with multiple assemblies

Tags: code-coverage, opencover

I am trying to combine three unit testing projects (three different dlls) into one OpenCover report. Is it possible? I tried to look into filters but I don't see enough detail (examples) in the OpenCover Wiki site. Can someone shed some lights on where I can start?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Kevin Up, Yup, nunit. And just curious, does it also work for VSTS?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes it is possible. If you are using nunit (or some other test runner) you can (usually) run all test assemblies at the same time

e.g.

```
opencover.console.exe 
    -register:user 
    "-target:nunit-console.exe" 
    "-targetargs:test1.dll test2.dll /noshadow" 
    "-filter:+[*]* -[test*]*"
```

alternatively if you are using different test runners (or multiple runs using the same test runner) then you can run them separately and merge the results using [reportgenerator](http://reportgenerator.codeplex.com/) to create a single html report.

If you have any specific issues please comment below for clarification.

Answer (score 5):

Since november 2014 (v4.5.3427), the `-mergeoutput` option was added by @Shaun Wilde.

It allows to merge an existing file with the same name as defined with `-output`.

Answer (score 1):

You can give a chance to this powershell script https://github.com/rpokrovskij/opencover4vs.ps1/blob/master/opencover4vs.ps1

It will help you to atomize the work of creating those long "-targetargs:test1.dll test2.dll" parameters.